# Valence API returning http 403 after a month

Tags: authentication, desire2learn

I have been successfully using the D2L Valence API for about a month, but this past
weekend, all API calls return a 403 error. I contacted the support team in
charge of our D2L server, but they said nothing changed over the weekend.
They're still looking into the issue. I've tried 3 different users that
have different permission settings, but all of them fail. Do you know what
could cause this? Is there some kind of spam filtering, or a limit of
requests per hour? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The 403 may have additional body to indicate more information. If you are saving the userid and userkey the body may be "Token Expired". This is a possible cause because some servers have a 30 day expiry.

If you are using an interactive app a 403 with "Token Expired" can be used to reprompt the user for auth (if you are using the library it will tell you that you need to reauth in the interpretResult() call. )  Apps also need to be able to do this in the event of a password reset as tokens are expired when a password is reset.

If you are not using an interactive app (or if you prefer avoiding the reauth) Desire2Learn support can update the token expiry to be indefinite (your institution support team can open a ticket with Desire2Learn support to have this changed: d2l.Security.API.TokenTimeout should go to -1).